# Is byte code directly executed by python virtual machine or is it converted to machine code and executed by python virtual machine?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, bytecode, interpreter

byte code directly executed by python virtual machine or is it converted to machine code and executed by python virtual machine ?

[python docs bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytecode) states below
*This “intermediate language” is said to run on a virtual machine that executes the machine code corresponding to each bytecode.*

I read all question in stackoverflow related to PVM,bytecode the last part of python code exeuction is not explained clearly by anyone

which of below 2 flow is correct ?

1. byte code is converted to machine code by VM and VM execute the machine code? what dose the CPU do then here is it idle ?
2. byte code is converted to machine code by VM and VM send machine code to CPU for execution ?

Comment: Bytecode is not converted to machine code in CPython.

Comment: @ user2357112 please refer the python  doc link it says conversion happens ,so how do you think the result is published machines only understand binary instructions/machine code

Comment: No it doesn't. Nowhere in that documentation does it say any such conversion happens.

Comment: It's basically just a giant switch statement. Is the bytecode opcode this value? Then do this thing. Is it this other value? Then do this other thing. (It's not quite *just* a switch, because there's a computed goto optimization.) You can read the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Python/ceval.c#L1323) if you want.

Comment: "what dose the CPU do then here is it idle ?" The CPU executes the VM. If the CPU were idle, nothing would happen.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica , thanks for the infromation,   its says "VM  executes the machine code corresponding to each bytecode."  if no conversion happens why python document talks about executing machine code ?    so  correct if i'm wrong you mean to say VM has a switch statement that executes bytecode based on different opcode ?  who displays the results is it VM or CPU ?  if VM can do all the work then CPU is there just to initiate the VM and it dose nothing else ?

Comment: @sepp2k  Finally at end of day  machine only understand machine code right ,what is right out of below 2 ?  1. VM is powerful software that i can mimic CPU  so VM execute byte code and converts result into machine code and   displays result in screen   or 2. VM converts bytecode to  machine code  and sends to CPU for execution and CPU display result in screen

Comment: @star What's true is that the VM is a program that executes the byte code. I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about converting the result to machine code though. How would you convert non-executable data to machine code? The VM prints stuff by calling some print function that in turn invokes the appropriate system call - same as any other program. Nothing is converted to machine code (except the source code of the VM itself to create the executable that you're running).

Comment: @sepp2k please find below detailed comments form Michael Dyck the flow that was said sounds valid ,i guess no one is having a clear picture of the last part of python code execution , im waiting for Michael Dyck to share some links/soruce from   where he got the information .

Comment: I already saw and upvoted that answer. If you're implying that it contradicts my statement "Nothing is converted to machine code (*except the source code of the VM itself to create the executable that you're running*)." (or anything else I've said), you've either misunderstood the answer or my comments.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say that each bytecode instruction consists of an opcode and zero or more operands. There's a fixed small set of opcodes and (in general) a fairly large set of operands.

For each different opcode, the source code of the VM has some code that implements that opcode. All that source code is then compiled to machine code. So within the machine code of the VM, there is machine code for each opcode.

When the CPU executes the machine code of the VM, the VM repeatedly executes the next bytecode instruction by looking at its opcode and then switching/jumping to the chunk of machine code that implements that opcode, passing it the operands.

At no point in this process are whole bytecode instructions translated into equivalent machine code, so neither of your 'flows' is correct.

When the Python docs say that the VM "executes the machine code corresponding to each bytecode", that's a bit imprecise. Only the CPU executes machine code. Specifically, the CPU, as it executes the machine code of the VM, will execute the machine code corresponding to each opcode that appears in the input bytecode.

Comment: this explanation was really helpful can you share the link from where you got to know about this details ?

Comment: I learned this stuff too long ago to attribute it to a specific link. If you search for "Python virtual machine", you should find some helpful articles and videos.

Comment: You say "the VM repeatedly executes the next bytecode instruction by looking at its opcode and then switching/jumping to the chunk of machine code that implements that opcode, passing it the operands."
I don't understand why we can't call this procedure "translation of a bytecode instruction into the equivalent machine code instruction". At the input we have a bytecode instruction, and at the output we have the equivalent machine code instruction (which then executed by the CPU). Technical details of conversion don't matter!

Comment: Indeed, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translator_(computing)) says: "Translation is a generic term that can refer to a compiler, assembler, or **interpreter** — anything that converts code from one computer language into another. These include translations between high-level languages such as C++ and Java, intermediate-level languages such as Java bytecode, low-level languages such as the machine code, and between similar levels of language on different computing platforms, as well as from any of these to any other of these." Python bytecode is just an intermediate-level language.

Comment: If you say that the Python VM "translates a bytecode instruction into the equivalent machine code instruction", or that the VM's 'output' is machine code, then that can lead to confusion such as in the original question.

Comment: Well, there will be no confusion if I add in the end of the first quote the following: "right after that this machine code is executed by the CPU". So, basically, I can't see enough evidence for why the "flow 2" from the OP is wrong – if by "translation" (conversion) we mean the specific procedure for how the Python VM reads the bytecode instruction's opcode, then finds the appropriate chunk of machine code in the VM's executable file and filling it with the operands. Indeed, Python VM is essentialy a bytecode interpreter.

Comment: And every interpreter internally do some sort of translation work (wikipedia even classified them as translators, but translation is not their main goal).
Of course, in the "flow 2" of the opening post it should be clarified that translation (conversion) is done for one bytecode instruction per time (not for the full bytecode .pyc file at once - it has many instructions). After the CPU executed the resulted chunk of machine code, the Python VM starts to interpret the next bytecode instruction. So we have a loop through the bytecode instructions.

Comment: Sure, if you define "translation" to include the activity of a VM, then you can say that a VM translates to machine code. I still think this leads to confusion. The Python VM does not generate a 'chunk of machine code' for the CPU to then execute.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a language.  CPython is the reference implementation of Python.

CPython does not JIT out of the box, but you can get a simple JIT for CPython with numba.

Also, there is at least one implementation of the Python language that JIT's out of the box: Pypy.

(A "JIT" converts byte code to machine code for performance)

Comment: i agree with you n JIT as its very clear there is a machine code conversion takes place but Cpython has PVM that  executes byte code so the question is how is byte code result understood by machine ? machine understands only binary code